# How do I solve an error related with APIs

Tags: python, request, rapidapi

i wold like to obtain info about an API but I get this error:

> {"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."}

How can I solve this? My code is this one:

```
import requests
url = "https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com/title/get-top-stripe"
querystring = {"currentCountry":"US","purchaseCountry":"US","tconst":""}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': ""
    }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: you need to create an account with rapidapi and use the token they provide you to authenticate against their API. you can subscribe here: https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/imdb8

Comment: I've done it and it worked!!Thanks,now how do I hide my personnal token??

Comment: if you will use it to create web page then token is hidden on server and users have no access to this token. But if you want to create desktop application then you can't hide it. You can only ask user to register on rapidapi to get own token.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to subscribe to a particular API on RapidAPI Hub. You can do that by visiting the pricing page of an API. I believe you're using [IMDb API](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/imdb8/). The Basic plan is free of this IMDb API.

You can subscribe to any API by following the steps below:

```
Search API -> Go to the Pricing page -> Choose a plan (according to your need) -> Click on Subscribe button.
```

Once you subscribed, you would be able to test and connect to an API.